# tidy_parse_string expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Tags: php, tidy

I have HTML tidy extension on my home computer using PHP 5.2.11 (Windows - WAMP), and I use this to clean up HTML:

```
$data = tidy_parse_string($data, array(
   'clean'  => TRUE,
   'indent'  => 0,
   'output-xhtml' => true,
   'wrap'  => 7000,
   ));
```

This works great on my home machine, but on the actual server on which the website runs (LAMP), I get the error:

```
tidy_parse_string expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in....
```

The phpinfo() on my local machine gives a version number:

```
2.0 ($Id: tidy.c 272374 2008-12-31 11:17:49Z sebastian $)
```

But the phpinfo() on the server does not give a version. If I can't get a *nix version that accepts configuration (why on earth can't it?), then how do I pass these config vars to tidy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're running an old version of the Tidy PECL extension. Try updating it:

```
pecl update-channels
pecl upgrade
```

That should correct it, hope it helps!